# Restkit: How to use ResponseMapping without id attributes for a relationship with RKAssignmentPolicyUnion for a one to many relationship

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

In RestKit, when using a `RKEntityMapping`, if a relationship mapping does not have any identification attributes set, by default, the entire set of child objects get replaced even if the relationship assignment policy is set to `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion`.

Is there a way to get around this limitation?

It seems that in case of a relationship mapping, all existing objects are loaded, if no identificationAttributes are present. Then it simply returns the first available object

from `RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource`:

```c
- (id)mappingOperation:(RKMappingOperation *)mappingOperation targetObjectForRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation withMapping:(RKObjectMapping *)mapping inRelationship:(RKRelationshipMapping *)relationship



// If we are mapping within a relationship, try to find an existing object without identifying attributes
    // NOTE: We avoid doing the mutable(Array|Set|OrderedSet)ValueForKey if there are identification attributes for performance (see issue GH-1232)
    if (relationship) {
        NSArray *identificationAttributes = [entityMapping.identificationAttributes valueForKey:@"name"];
        id existingObjectsOfRelationship = identificationAttributes ?   [mappingOperation.destinationObject valueForKeyPath:relationship.destinationKeyPath] :   RKMutableCollectionValueWithObjectForKeyPath(mappingOperation.destinationObject,  relationship.destinationKeyPath);
        if (existingObjectsOfRelationship && !RKObjectIsCollection(existingObjectsOfRelationship)) existingObjectsOfRelationship = @[ existingObjectsOfRelationship ];
        for (NSManagedObject *existingObject in existingObjectsOfRelationship) {
            if (! identificationAttributes && ![existingObject isDeleted]) {
                managedObject = existingObject;
                [existingObjectsOfRelationship removeObject:managedObject];
                break;
            }

            NSDictionary *identificationAttributeValues = [existingObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:identificationAttributes];
            if ([[NSSet setWithArray:[identificationAttributeValues allValues]] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithObject:[NSNull null]]]) {
                managedObject = existingObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you turned on debug logging and searched the log for 'union'? I expect it should work just with duplicates.

Comment: thanks Wain. I edited the original question to highlight where i think the issue exists. Its specifically in case of mapping a relationship when there are already objects in the relationship.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add identification attributes? Can you just add all attributes?

Comment: yes good point. Ideally all remote resources will have some discerning identification attributes. I have a case in which api response does not have identifiers and just adding all attributes could result in duplicates.

Comment: How will adding all attributes result in duplicates compared to having no attributes?

Comment: Yes fair point. I revisited the response. It seems that the object I am trying to map only has a one id attribute, some metadata mapped attributes and sometimes the id attribute is absent. It seems weird from an API standpoint. Maybe I can inject the id attribute into JSON response prior to mapping.

Comment: Wain - is it possible to use @metadata as part of the identifier attributes? Something like myMapping.identificationAttributes = @[  @"@metadata.mapping.collectionIndex"];

Comment: Not quite like that, but yes. You need to add a non-transient attribute in the data model and map the metadata into that. Then set the id to that new attribute. Note that the collection index is only unique within the context of each request...